# Ensuring constant window size in pandas rolling window function

Tags: python, pandas

A some custom operation needs to be done on each rolling window of size 2 in a dataframe. But `rolling` function in pandas, returns an output with initial window location with 1 element as well. I tried setting the `min_periods`, but does not help here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]})

for pairs in df.rolling(2, min_periods=2):
    print(pairs)

     B
0  0.0
     B
0  0.0
1  1.0
     B
1  1.0
2  2.0
     B
2  2.0
3  NaN
     B
3  NaN
4  4.0
```

Also indexing doesn't work for rolling function. Getting the following error for df.rolling(2)[1:]

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: Try doing `df.rolling(2, min_periods=2).apply(lambda x: 1)`.  `min_periods` is considered in the successive call.

Answer (score 4):

You could use numpy's [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html)

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(df.B, 2)
```

```
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2., nan],
       [nan,  4.]])
```