# pandas rolling function min_periods argument

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compute values on a sliding window from the points those are complete (ie: skipping the initial ones). I tried to use `min_periods` for that but it does not help.
I specify `min_periods` to the window size but I still get windows that are smaller than the specified value.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'1.5.3'
>>> [list(x) for x in pd.Series(range(5)).rolling(window=3, min_periods=3)]
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72982735/ensuring-constant-window-size-in-pandas-rolling-window-function). Still I think this is not the expected behaviour given `min_periods` description.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are looping manually over the `rolling` object, which ignores the `min_periods`.

If you used a rolling function (e.g., [`rolling.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.min.html)), the values would be ignored:

```
pd.Series(range(5)).rolling(window=3, min_periods=3).min()
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
```

Another example with [`rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html):

```
pd.Series(range(5)).rolling(window=3, min_periods=3).apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
dtype: float64
```

Note that the computation is really only run for the groups with the chosen min periods. Using a small hack to see the used groups we can check that the groups with less than 3 values are never evaluated:

```
(pd.Series(range(5)).rolling(window=3, min_periods=3)
   .apply(lambda x: bool(print(x))) # this will return False/0
)

0    0.0       # this will be used to compute index 2
1    1.0
2    2.0
dtype: float64
1    1.0       # this will be used to compute index 3
2    2.0
3    3.0
dtype: float64
2    2.0       # this will be used to compute index 4
3    3.0
4    4.0
dtype: float64

# output
0    NaN       # this was never evaluated
1    NaN       #
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
dtype: float64
```